# How to remove empty cells in csv python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why the code below

```
with open('book.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

    for a in reader:
        print(a)
```

returns empty cells too.

```
['username', '', '', '']
['\t\t\t\t', '', '', '']
['Name', 'Surname', '', '']
['Brian', 'Fespa', '', '']
['John', 'Mc', '', '']
['\t\t\t\t', '', '', '']
['Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Sex']
['Lauren', 'Fon', '15', 'F']
['Tim', 'Matthew ', '25', 'M']
```

My purpose is to calculate the length of the rows that have actually some data. For example, the first list `['username', '', '', '']` should return length of 1 and not 4. The second list `['\t\t\t\t', '', '', '']` should return 0 and not 4.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If it didn't include empty cells, how would you know which cells in that row actually contain data?

Comment: It returns empty cells becuase its splitting the CSV. If you dont want empty cells then you should drop them after csv reader gives you the cells. What if there is a line like `'1','','2'`. should this show 2 or 3 since the middle is empty, should it be dropped?

Comment: What if you had 10 columns and only one had something in one column and it chose to just give you that non-empty column as a single item... what column is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to ignore empty cells maybe something like this will be useful, I also handled `\t` via `re`:

```
import csv
import re

with open('book.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    result = [[items for items in row if items != '' and items == re.sub('\t+','\t',items)] for row in reader]

print result
```

the book.csv file is :

```
username,,,
\t\t\t\t,,,
Name,Surname,,
Brian,Fespa,,
John,Mc,,
\t\t\t\t,,,
Name,Surname,Age,Sex
Lauren,Fon,15,F
Tim,Matthew,25,M
```

output is :

```
[['username'], 
[], 
['Name', 'Surname'], 
['Brian', 'Fespa'], 
['John', 'Mc'], 
[], 
['Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Sex'], 
['Lauren', 'Fon', '15', 'F'], 
['Tim', 'Matthew', '25', 'M']]
```

Comment: Except `'\t\t\t\t'` won't fail that test and still be included...

Comment: So, how can I delete the empty values within a list & empty rows?

Comment: It works! Can you "translate" the list comprehension that you used? I'm familiar with simple list comprehension syntaxes.

Comment: @JonClements is it ok now ?

Comment: @zimskiz please check it again, I removed `\t\t` too !